# how to create a special sparse matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have some matlab code that creates a sparse matrix.
I want to create the sparse matrix in the following way:

```
    messages_llr_matrix = ...
        sparse(II,JJ,code_word_aprior_prob(JJ)+TEMP_ONE,ROW_NUM,COL_NUM);
```

That means that the matrix will only hold values that are specified by II, JJ
indexes.

The problem is that the values represented by: "code_word_aprior_prob(JJ)",
can be zeros and are in need for the rest of the code. Those values are omitted.

I have tried to look for some online, unsuccessfully.

Comment: it doesnt make sense. the amount of nonzeroes is different to the amount of indexes if you do this.

Comment: Allow me to clarify: II, JJ in the above code are the relevant indexes. All indexes not specified should be omitted. The problem is that i want to save also the indexes II, JJ in  which code_word_aprior_prob(JJ) is zero.

Comment: But, having a sparse matrix with entries equals to zero defies the whole purpose of sparse matrices....

Comment: An sparse matrix is a matrix that is mainly filled with zeros. As you know that all mainly all is zero, you dont want to save that. Thus you create an structure where you save everything that is not zero. And the rest is assumed to be zero. Thus, in sparse matrices, the value is **the deal**. Do not save zero values, just assume that if something is not a saved value, then is zero

Comment: Yes, i understand. OK.